# memory size exhausted with laravel soft delete action

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5.6 when i try to Soft Delete all data in table with large records with my function:

```
public function clearActivityLog() {
    $activities = Activity::all();

    foreach ($activities as $activity) {
        $activity->delete();
    }

    return redirect('admin/activity')
        ->with('success', trans('backend/main.logs.activity.messages.logClearedSuccessfuly'));
}
```

I get this error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jerodev's answer is a good one in this scenario.

In some cases, you can't do a bulk update (like if you need to do processing on each item, or if you need Eloquent events to fire). In those cases, you can avoid running out of memory by using [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#chunking-results):

```
Activity::chunk(100, function($activities) {
    foreach ($activities as $activity) {
        $activity->delete();
    }
});
```

Doing this fetches only 100 (you can pick any number here) at a time into memory (versus `Activity::all()`, which loads *every single activity* into memory at once; if that's millions of rows, you can easily understand why you'd get a memory error).

Comment: I like this because if for whatever reason soft deletes eventually gets turned into hard deletes, this will continue to work.

Comment: So would `Activity::query()->delete();` and it requires one db query instead of one for each and every activity in the database.

Answer (score 3):

If there are lots of activities this could potentially generate an enormous amount of queries. This could be done with one query like so:

```
Activity::query()->update('deleted_at', now());
```

`softdeletes` uses the `deleted_at` column to check if the row is deleted. So setting the column manually for all rows gives the same effect.

Comment: good answer but Non-static method update() should not be called statically

Comment: Fixed by putting `query()` first.

Answer (score 1):

A more "eloquent" solution (and probably more future proof)

```
Activity::query()->delete();
```

This retrieves a query builder for the Activity model with no restrictions so the delete() will apply to all.  It does not load all the Activities up but instead deletes them in one call.  It also shows no knowledge of the inner working of soft deletes which is preferable for forward compatibility.

Comment: i tried this answer before i post my problem and its just delete all records but not soft delete.

Comment: Please double check that this is true and if so report as a bug to the Laravel team on github

Comment: you right work as well, but i don't know why i had such problem!! any way thanks all.